# How to wire the bean from xml into @Component?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am trying to customize a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` class to extend the logic:

```
@Component("superAuthenticaionProvider")
public class SuperAuthenticaionProvider extends PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider{

    // this is inherited from PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider
    /*private AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService;*/

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        .......
    }
}
```

Inherited from `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider`, a `preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService` is required to inject to the class, I make the injection in the xml:

**AuthenticationManager**

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref='preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider'/>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

**Customized authentication provider**

```
<bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.myapps.save.the.world.SuperAuthenticaionProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" 
    ref="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"/>
</bean>
```

**Inject preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService bean**

```
    <bean id="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.
        PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService"/>
```

But Spring framework gives me exception:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationUserDetailsService must be set
```

And

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationUserDetailsService must be set
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.afterPropertiesSet(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.java:44)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
... 26 more
```

The exception is about **An AuthenticationUserDetailsService must be set**
meaning the `preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService` is failed to inject into the class, but apparently it is in the `security-context.xml`.

Even I made the `AuthenticationUserDetailsService` to be `@Autowired` in the `AuthenticationProvider` class

```
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> 
                preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService;
```

It still gives me same error
So what did i miss here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have AuthenticationUserDetailsService set before using PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider. Can you provide more code of your custom auth provider or is that it? As doc says:

> This authentication provider will not perform any checks on
>   authentication  * requests, as they should already be
>   pre-authenticated. However, the  * AuthenticationUserDetailsService
>   implementation may still throw a UsernameNotFoundException, for
>   example.

Comment: Thanks. Yest that's it. But How can I initiate `AuthenticationUserDetailsService` before `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider`?

Comment: I see that `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` has a method called `setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService` which would take your UserDetails service bean as an argument? Maybe you can find something on that.

Comment: Right. I think that should make the `preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService` field qualified as a bean to autowire. So I set it in the xml in the question. But still get the same exception. Weird.